# Returning all data in one row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In my Postgresql Database, I have multiple reference data tables.
Example:

```
 - Gender(id:Serial, name:varchar)
 - Sexuality(id:Serial, name:varchar)
 - Location(id:Serial,name:varchar)
```

To retrieve all of the information in all of the tables I am doing 3 separate select statements.
Example:

```
 - "SELECT name from Gender;
 - "SELECT name from Sexuality;
 - "SELECT name from Location;
```

How can I make this into one call so that it returns one row like this:

```
ReferenceData(allGenders:varchar[], allSexualities:varchar[], allLocations:varchar[])
```

I would like to be able to be able to do something like this client side -->

```
var genders = results.row[0].allGenders;
for gender in genders {
   print(gender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `array_agg` aggragate function to combine values from multiple rows into a single array, e.g.

```
SELECT array_agg(name) FROM Gender
```

will return all genders as a single array. If you want all the information from all 3 tables at once, you can do it like that:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT array_agg(name) FROM Gender),
    (SELECT array_agg(name) FROM Sexuality),
    (SELECT array_agg(name) FROM Location);
```